# In IE11 .xls gets downloaded as .htm any pointers

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

In IE11 .xls gets downloaded as .htm any pointers.
This works fine in Chrome and Firefox but is not working in IE11 when the code is deployed in the server, it works in my local.
We are using Twitter-Bootstrap and Angular JS.

The code goes like this

```
             <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-4 col-xs-10" style="margin-top: 30px;">
                  <label class="text_style">Click here to download the template:</label> 

                  <div  class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="margin-left: -14px;">
                    <input allign="center" class="btn btn-custom" id="DownJSONbtn" name="DownJSONbtn"
                            type="button"  value="Download" ng-click="DownloadJSONtoExcel(REfTYpe);"/>
```

JS Function

```
$('#DownJSONbtn').html('<iframe src="assets/images/SAMPLE.xlsx" width="100" height="100"></iframe>');
```

The data comes via a webservice call to the back end.

Comment: That is not an XLS file so technically, IE11 is right... What content type header is your server sending along with the file? If you compare the headers between your local server and the live one, it might be the solution

Comment: Adding this(Content Type) makes it to work when the sheet comes from the back end but if the iframe picks up a sheet from the GUI\Client folder itself then it again gives the same problem. We dont want to call the WS and hence trying to see if there is a better way out.

Comment: did you find the root cause ? what was the solution ?